# Сокеты и вебсокеты, в чем разница на практике?

Tags: python, сокет, websocket

В питоне есть две библиотеки socket и websockets, я нашел информацию по ним отдельно, определения читал, но самой сути, где и что используется так и не понял, если вы знаете что пишут на сокетах, а что на вебсокетах и в чем их разница простыми словами, то буду благодарен получить ответ.

Comment: Вебсокеты тоже используют обычные сокеты внутри себя

Comment: В общем-то, сокеты - это единственный способ взаимодействия с другими устройствами по сети в современных системах. Всё остальное работает на базе этих сокетов (в том числе вебсокеты)